# Como usar o "in" do SQL em uma função lambda (entity) C#?

Tags: c#, expressões-lambda

Eu tenho um repositório que representa minha tabela no banco de dados

```
    var RelacaoPessoas = _repositoryPessoas.GetFiltered(i => i.IdProcesso == idprocesso && i.Banco == numeroDoBanco && i.CpfCnpj.Contains(cpfCnpj)).ToList();
```

Eu preciso resgatar os registros a partir de uma lista de Cpf's, em sql seria algo assim:

```
    select * from Pessoas where IdProcesso = @idprocesso and Banco = @numeroBanco and CpfCnpj in (<lista de cpfs aqui>)
```

Porém, eu não sei qual seria a função equivalente ao "in". Eu sei que o "Contains" aceita string, eu tentei passar essa minha lista como uma string separada por vírgula dessa forma:  "cpf1,cpf2,cpf3..." mas não deu certo.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: A syntax aparentemente está ok,  o  Contaisn é o  equivalente ao  in, porem algum dado da sua query  deve estar retornando  false já verificou se  idprocesso e numeroDoBanco  estão  com valores esperados no  banco  ?

Comment: Marcos, Contains seria equivalente ao "like" do sql, então como eu tava passando como pararamento "cpf1,cpf2,cpf3...", em sql seria o mesmo que "select * from tabela where cpf like 'cpf1,cpf2,cpf3...' ". Por esse motivo não estava retornadno nada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se você tem uma lista de CPFs você pode fazer algo mais ou menos assim:

Imagine que sua lista de CPFs para filtros estejam armazenados na seguinte variável:

```
var listCpfParaFiltro = new List<string>();
```

Na hora de fazer o filtro codifique assim:

```
var RelacaoPessoas = _repositoryPessoas.GetFiltered(i => i.IdProcesso == idprocesso && i.Banco == numeroDoBanco && listCpfParaFiltro.Contains(i.CpfCnpj)).ToList();
```

Comment: Obrigado Thiago. Eu já havia criado uma lista de string, só que eu coloquei essa lista dentro do Contains(), ou seja, a sintaxe estava ao contrário mesmo. Obrigado mesmo pela ajuda, funcionou e a consulta retornou como esperado